# Correctness of implicit completed nonblocking MPI send

Tags: mpi

considering the following code:

```
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  if( rank == 0) {
    MPI_Isend(&a, 1, MPI_REAL, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r1);
    MPI_Recv(&b, 1, MPI_REAL, 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    // [ WORK/UPDATE ON a ]
    MPI_Wait(&r1, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  else if( rank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(&a, 1, MPI_REAL, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Isend(&b, 1, MPI_REAL, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &r2);
  }
```

The MPI specification 4.1 says about accessing/updating `a` in chapter 3.7:

> A separate send complete call is needed to complete the communication, i.e., to verify that the data has been copied out of the send buffer

and in chapter 3.7.3 it says

> The completion of a send operation indicates that the sender is now free to update the send buffer

But in this example the blocking receive from rank 1 must have been completed before its nonblocking send is executed, which triggers the blocking receive in rank 0. Only after this the variable `a` is accessed and updated somehow. Even though the corresponding `MPI_Wait` happens afterwards, is this still valid (resp. specification obeying) code?

(I think I read in the specification somewhere that a completed recv operation means a successful copy of the send buffer, but I can't find the passage anymore. This would mean that it is legal to access the send buffer even though there was no corresponding completion operation, yet?)

Comment: I would say this code is invalid with respect to the MPI Standard. For example, if you run with Open MPI and memory debugging, the `a` buffer is marked as read-only by `MPI_Isend()` until `MPI_Wait()` completes, so your code will crash. It will work just fine in most cases though, but I do not think you should take it for granted.